# How can I solve this pm2 log errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

[image][image]I installed pm2 but it occurs some errors.
(I installed pm2 with "npm install pm2 -g")

But I don't know how to deal with these errors.

How should I solve this error?

node.js version: **10.15.1**,
pm2 version: **3.3.0**,
os: **windows 7**

**pm2.log**

```
Error caught while calling pidusage
Error: Error: spawn wmic ENOENT
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\pidusage\lib
\bin.js:33:10)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:211:7)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:196:12)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:362:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
|Error caught while calling pidusage
Error: Error: spawn wmic ENOENT
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\pidusage\lib
\bin.js:33:10)
```

Comment: have you succeeded in solving this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

`wmic` is not available on your system, check `C:\WINDOWS\System32\wbem` folder.

Please check also if `C:\WINDOWS\System32\wbem` is in system PATH environment variable.

Comment: What's the easyest way to get this on my system?

Answer (score 0):

What is your npm version? I think you should upgrade it version, remove node_modules folder, clear cache and run `npm install` again.